# Search doesnt return matching results

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, next.js

```
const searchClientes = (e) => {
  if (e.target.value === '') {
    getClientes();
    return;
  } else {
    const search = e.target.value;

    const filteredClientes = clientes.filter(clientes => {
       return clientes.nome.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) || 
                clientes.email.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase());
      })
    setClientes(filteredClientes);
  }
}
```

In this code, if i delete a character or characters, the function doesnt return to me matching results. Only show me all clients if i delete everything. Someone can give me some solution for matching results as soon as i delete something from the search?

Answer (score 0):

Here can use debouncing here, which function invoked after a certain delay

just add `debouncedSearchClientes` function to input element

```
const debounce = (fn, delay) => {
  let timeoutId;
  return function (...args) {
    if (timeoutId) {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    }
    timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      fn(args);
    }, delay);
  };
}

const searchClientes = (e) => {
  const search = e.target.value;
  const filteredClientes = clientes.filter((clients) => {
    return (
      clients.nome.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) ||
      clients.email.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
    );
  });
  setClientes(filteredClientes);
};

const debouncedSearchClientes = debounce(searchClientes, 750);
```

Comment: That doesnt solve it. If i delete it, still doesnt give me matches. Only show me all clientes if i delete everything.